# How to transfer ONE photo FROM PC to iPhone 6

Tags: iphone, itunes, icloud, photos

From time-to-time I want to transfer only one or a very few photos FROM my PC (Windows 7) to my iPhone (currently an iPhone 6).

I can find plenty of advice on how to transfer from the iPhone to the PC, but there seems to be a dearth (severe lack) of info on how to do the converse.

I have iCloud, Wifi, iTunes, and a cable. I (and I'm sure another of 10K of your best friends) will be grateful for instructions that are "written for grandma." (I'm not a grandma, but I am a late adopter.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Apple way is to pick a folder on your PC for sync. You do this through iTunes, by connecting your phone and picking the photos tab. Full information here: http://support.apple.com/kb/ht4236

However, if it's just 1 or 2 photos, the easiest way is to use Dropbox (you have Dropbox right?). Put the photo in your Dropbox, go to the same folder using the Dropbox app on your phone, click on the photo, click the little share button in bottom left, and then choose "Save Image."

Comment: Bowen, I had Dropbox on my PC but not elsewhere. Now I do. Your instructions worked like a charm. 8^} Thank you!

Comment: Glad I could help! Feel free to mark as accepted =)

Comment: Apologies for my very belated acceptance of your answer, Bowen. I thought I'd done so way back in Oct. and while looking through my account today I discovered I hadn't. Your guidance was excellent. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Go to iTunes. Click on your iPhone/iPod/iPad. Go to Photos. If the "Sync All Photos" option is checked, un check it. You can reenable it later. Then, select your photo, and hit sync.

Comment: This is actually the first thing I tried, but I was unable to transfer my photos from my PC into iTunes.

Comment: @RJo Bowen's answer is probably your best bet, then.

Comment: I'm still going to try your suggestion as well. It's good to have alternatives.

To paraphrase a point in my original post, I'm a late adopter. A very late adopter. 

98% of my cellphone use is to talk to people and to listen to audiobooks.

I thought I'd be able to just drag-n-drop my photos into iTunes (and maybe onto my phone when it was connected to iTunes), but it did not appear to work.