# Deleted photos from phone when transfering to macbook, how to get back on phone?

Tags: iphone, icloud, photos, photos.app

I transferred photos from my iphone to my macbook, but turns out the photos were deleted from my phone after the transfer. So now I have the photos on my macbook but not on the phone.

I'm trying to get those photos back on my phone.

I tried changing preferences such that icloud would work on my phone and macbook, but it did not work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/152394/how-to-transfer-one-photo-from-pc-to-iphone-6?rq=1. Not the same question, but definitely related.

Answer (score 1):

When plugging your iPhone into your MacBook, in iTunes when accessing your phone, you should be able to select 'Photos' from the Settings tab on the left, then press `Sync Photos`, then choose the photo folder that you want to sync back into your iPhone. Then press `Apply`.

Note: before choosing the folder, you need to create a separate folder containing all the pictures that you want to sync back.